# MySql WHERE with counted aggregated column - not possible, so what's the solution?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT P.id
     , P.capacity
     , COUNT(EP.project_id) AS Total 
  FROM project P 
  LEFT 
  JOIN service_user_enquiry_project EP 
    ON EP.project_id = P.id 
 WHERE P.capacity > 0 
 GROUP 
    BY P.id;
```

In my query above, i need to have it return results where P.capacity > 0 OR "Total" > 0 but i can't use "Total" in the WHERE clauses, and HAVING isn't going to work in this case, because i need either or, not just WHERE capacity > 0 and having Total > 0

Essentially need records from "project" if capacity is greater that 0 OR the count of the joined table is greater than 0.

I'm sure i used to be able to use aggregated columns in the WHERE clause. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check this SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fc00a/5

```
SELECT P.id, P.capacity,COUNT(EP.project_id) AS Total 
FROM project P 
    LEFT JOIN service_user_enquiry_project EP ON EP.project_id = P.id 
GROUP BY(P.id)
HAVING Total > 0 OR P.capacity > 0;
```